# How to bind a key for selected text in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublimetext-snippet

So I have a text for example "`this is sample text`" and I want it to become this "`<![CDATA[this is sample text]]>`"

I want to work this function like this: I select any text and use hotkey like <kbd>ctrl+t</kbd> or so.

I use Sublime Text 3.

How can I do this for the selection of text?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new keybinding to use the `insert_snippet` command to wrap your selection. (Preferences menu -> Keybindings)

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<![CDATA[${0:$SELECTION}]]>"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank You!